# MATLAB help cropping an image

Tags: image, matlab, crop

I am using MATLAB R2012a and I am trying to let the user crop the image WITHOUT the use of the built in function.
here is my code:

```
[x, y] = ginput(2);
m1 = [x(1), y(1)];
m2 = [x(2), y(2)];
m1 = int16(m1);
m2 = int16(m2);
[m, n] = size(manip);
s1 = (m2(1) - m1(1))+1;
s2 = (m2(2) - m2(2))+1;
temp = zeros([s1, s2],('uint8'));
p1 = 0;
p2 = 0;
for c1 = 1:m
    if ((c1 <= m1(2)) && (c1 >= m2(2)))
        for c2 = 1:n
            if ((c2 <= m1(1)) && (c2 >= m2(1)))
                temp(p1, p2) = manip(c1, c2);
            end
            p2 = p2 + 1;
        end
    end
    p1 = p1 + 1;
end
out = temp;
```

and here is my result:

[image: results of the cropping]


Any ideas of what I did wrong, I can's seem to be able to see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine your error is here: `s2 = (m2(2) - m2(2))+1;` should this not be `s2 = (m2(2) - m1(2))+1;` ?

However you don't need that loop at all:

```
Iold = rand(300);
%crop 10 pixels off each side
Inew = Iold(11:end - 10, 11: end - 10);
```

or if you need the images the same size but with zeros where the cropped bits are:

```
Inew = zeros(size(Iold));
Inew(11:end - 10, 11: end - 10) = Iold(11:end - 10, 11: end - 10);
```

or to generalize it:

```
Inew(xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax) = Iold(xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax);
```